# Calculating the current

Tags: current

I recently got a power supply schematic for my project, but for the rest of the project I need to know how much current is being used on the AC input and I don't have the completed board yet to test it or I don't know how to calculate it.

(input `220V`)
(output `6.5V` `200mA`)

[image]

I also have an `AT Mega 8` on the out put !!!

Comment: Input AC voltage level is important to know as well as output current. I would also be concerned about the feedback circuit your schematic uses - it looks to me like there is no series resistor on the photodiode in the opto coupler.

Comment: It was in the datasheet of NCP1201.

Comment: Have you tried simulating it with something like LTSpice?

Comment: The photodiode has a max current of 60mA - if a data sheet doesn't show a resistor, it doesn't exempt you from the responsibility of understanding things correctly. You might get away without a resistor if the ESR of the zener isn't too low.

Comment: I agree with @Andy aka, the feedback circuit isn't optimal.  There's a temperature coefficient associated with Vf of the opto. The zener is in the approximate range where the tempco isn't too bad, but using a TL431 to drive the opto WITH a series resistor is the more conventional way to do it.  Any time you are not specifically limiting the current in a diode you run the risk of transients or overloads reducing lifetime or damaging the optocoupler/zener.

Answer (score 1):

Generally with this sot of circuit, power out = approximately 75% of power in.

If power out is 6.5 x 0.2 (= 1.3 watts) then power in will be about 1.73 watts. Given that the voltage in is 220 volts, the current in will be approximately 1.73/220 = 8mA.

However, there will be an AC component of the current flowing into the device that neither gets converted to useful output power nor heats anything. This is related to power factor and harmonic distortion of the current waveform.

This is hard to calculate but could be another 10mA on top of the 8mA that generates output power and heat.